# Elements affecting text-align:center of other elements

Tags: html, css, text-align

This is my code. I want the `TimeDisplay` to be at the same position but the title to still be centered inside that div.

```html
<html>
  <div style="background-color:seagreen; width:100%; height:12.5%; text-align:center; display:table;">
    <a style="color:aqua; font-family:Calibri; font-size:4vmax; font-weight:700; text-decoration:none; display:table-cell; vertical-align:middle;" href="Home.html">Soogbad's Website</a>
    <h2 id="TimeDisplay" style="color:aqua; font-family:Calibri; font-size:1.25vmax; display:table-cell; vertical-align:middle;">00/00/0000 00:00:00</h2>
  </div>
</html>
```

How do I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try using `style="position: absolute;"` for the TimeDisplay

Comment: Thanks didn't think of that